# How Can I Access All of The Keys in a JSON File Using IJSON kvitems?

Tags: python, jsonparser, ijson

I'm using ijson.kvitems to iterate over all of the keys in a JSON file that I have.

the JSON file looks like this:

```
{"filename":{"file_data":
{"name":"samplefile",
"filetype":"Miscellaneous",
"id":123,
"timestamp":"2020-10-08 00:20:00"}}}
```

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60314023/15853214), a simplified version of my code looks something like so (v is a dictionary too):

```
import ijson

f = open('file.json')
for k, v in ijson.kvitems(f, ''):
    name = v['name']
    user_id = v['id']
    filetype = v['filetype']
    timestamp = v['timestamp']
```

I am only able to stream/read about 94% of the keys from the original file this way, trying to figure out if there is a way to get to the remaining 6%.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please, post [mre], incl. imports and sample input JSON. Asking for recommendations for off-site resource is off-topic on SO.

Comment: I'd like to help, but from the question it's not clear what the exact problem is. In your example, which keys cannot be read? The example itself also seems wrong, because an empty path in `kvitems` should yield `filename` for `k` and the object under that key for `v`

Comment: AFAIK, the empty path should allow access to all of the keys (filenames) in the dictionary, and v should contain the nested dictionary ({"file_data": {"name":...}}), and this is how I use kvitems. my problem is that when iterating over k, v in ijson.kvitems(f, '') not all of the Ks (i.e. the filenames) are included in the iterator.

Comment: Sorry, but the exact problem is still not clear (at least to me). Can you modify the example JSON document and test code to show exactly which keys are missing? Note also that the way you are indexing into `v` in the example code wouldn't work with the given JSON document, since access should look like `v['file_data']['name']`, etc

Comment: I am unable to determine which keys are missing since there are a couple hundred-thousands of them, and the iteration takes forever (data is in a remote repo, long story).
regarding the access - the way I understand it, being the value for "filename" key - v *is* 'file_data' - you cannot access v['file_data']. What am I missing? thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `kvitems` maybe isn't fully clear: it returns key/value pairs at the given prefix, and it's not recursive. With your example document and code this is what `kvitems` returns (note that as of writing `ijson.dump` isn't yet on the latest PyPI ijson release, but is available on the latest `master` version on GitHub):

```sh
echo '{
  "filename": {
    "file_data": {
      "name":"samplefile",
      "filetype":"Miscellaneous",
      "id":123,
      "timestamp":"2020-10-08 00:20:00"
    }
  }
}' | python -m ijson.dump -m kvitems
```

```
#: key, value
-------------
0: filename, {'file_data': {'name': 'samplefile', 'filetype': 'Miscellaneous', 'id': 123, 'timestamp': '2020-10-08 00:20:00'}}
```

Here `key` is `filename`, while `value` is the rest of the object, since that whole object is the value under `filename`. In particular keys like `name` or `filetype` will not be reported separately; if you wanted those (and their respective values) to be reported you'd have to use a `filename.file_data` prefix instead.

From the comments in the original question I'm guessing this is the actual problem, but couldn't add this more extensive comment here to further clarify things, and with the hopes it's also the actual answer to your problem.